# Nuxt 3. Error running 'npm install' right after 'npx nuxi init <project name>'

Tags: vue.js, npm, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

Somehow today when I tried to create a new Nuxt 3 project using `npx nuxi init <project name>` as usual. The terminal gave me a long error when I tried to install the dependencies using `npm install`. I also tried deleting the `lock` file and using `yarn` & `pnpm` instead, however, the result is still the same.

Versions:

- Windows: Windows_NT 10.0.19044
- Node: v16.13.0
- Npm: v9.0.1
- Nuxt: 3.3.1

Error Message:

```
× Client
  Compiled with some errors in 9.90s

( ) Server

Hash: 2c24c5888bf3b1c1c416                                                                                    13:31:53
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 9899ms
Built at: 15/03/2023 1:31:53 pm
     Asset       Size  Chunks               Chunk Names
0f675ac.js   2.29 KiB       2  [immutable]  runtime
12a4221.js   4.75 KiB       4  [immutable]
1ab12b9.js   44.4 KiB       0  [immutable]  app
393869b.js    184 KiB       3  [immutable]  vendors/app
  LICENSES  336 bytes
ec6d84d.js   72.1 KiB       1  [immutable]  commons/app
Entrypoint app = 0f675ac.js ec6d84d.js 393869b.js 1ab12b9.js

WARNING in ./.nuxt/router.js 19:8-14
"export 'default' (imported as 'Router') was not found in 'vue-router'
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js

WARNING in ./.nuxt/router.js 34:19-25
"export 'default' (imported as 'Router') was not found in 'vue-router'
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js

// The WARNING continues for about 20 more items
//...
//...

ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs 2157:18-26
Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs 2158:30-38
Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
 @ ./.nuxt/router.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js

// The ERROR continues for about 20 more items.
//...
//...

 ERROR  Nuxt build error                                                                                      13:31:53

  at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (C:\Users\user\node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:2127:21)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async WebpackBundler.build (C:\Users\user\node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\dist\webpack.js:2076:5)
  at async Builder.build (C:\Users\user\node_modules\@nuxt\builder\dist\builder.js:327:5)
  at async Object.invoke (/C:/Users/user/projects/noah2/node_modules/nuxi/dist/chunks/prepare.mjs:45:5)
  at async _main (/C:/Users/user/projects/noah2/node_modules/nuxi/dist/cli.mjs:49:20)

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\projects\noah2
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c nuxt prepare

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-15T05_31_37_102Z-debug-0.log
```

That's all for my questions. Super thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading `nuxt` to `3.2.0` and using `pnpm` works for me.

this is my `package.json`

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.2.0"
  }
}
```